# how to get url value in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, get

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^Assamese/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) assamese.php?gender=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^Assamese/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) assamese.php?gender=$1&alp=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have to try this one case not yet working.please help me

Comment: if I can use both RewriteRule.i will get first rule only not yet get second rule parameter of both values in  that page .

Answer (score 0):

You can access the URL from PHP's $_SERVER super global, and specifically the REQUEST_URI index.

For example:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

The full list of variables/values available in this superglobal (including hostname, paths etc) is on [this page in the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

You might also find [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php) valuable.